# override create in serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Im overriding the create method in serializer but it seems it is not getting into this function when i do a POST request:

My serializer:

```
class ElsUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ElsUser
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', "email"]
        read_only_fields = ['id']

class RequisiteItemSerializser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = ElsUserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = RequisiteItem
        fields = ['id', 'enrollable', 'completed_within_days', 'completed_within_type','date_completed_by', 'created_by' ]
        read_only_fields = ['id']


class RequisiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = ElsUserSerializer()
    items = RequisiteItemSerializser(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Requisite
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'items', 'enrolments', 'created_by', 'timestamp')
        read_only_fields = ['id']
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("SELF INTITIAL DATA", self.initial_data)
        helper = RequisiteHelper()
        requisite = helper.create(self.initial_data,self.context['request'])
        print("LOGGES IN USER", self.context['request'].user.username)

        return requisite
```

I have moved the methods to a separate helper class:

My helper class:

```
class RequisiteHelper:
    def create(self, initial_data, context):
        name = initial_data['name']
        description = initial_data['description']
        items = initial_data['items']
        enrolments = initial_data['enrolments']
        requisite = Requisite.objects.create(name=name, description=description, created_by=context.user)
        self.create_items(requisite, items, context)
        self.create_enrolments(requisite, enrolments)
        requisite.save()
        return requisite

def create_items(self, requisite, items, context):
    for item in items:
        requisite_item = RequisiteItem()
        enrollable = Enrollable.objects.get(id=item.enrollable.id)
        requisite_item.enrollable = enrollable
        requisite_item.created_by = context.user
        requisite_item.completed_within_days = item.completed_within_days
        cw_type = CompletedWithinType.objects.get(short_name = item.completed_within_type)
        requisite_item.completed_within_type = cw_type
        requisite_item.save()
        requisite.items.add(requisite_item)

def create_enrolments(self, requisite, enrolments):
    for enrolment in enrolments:
        requisite.add(enrolment)
```

When i create a Requisite by post method,it keeps showing created_by is required. Im saving created_by automatically as logged in user by overrriding the create method. The print statements are also not displaying. What could i be doing wrong?

In views.py i have:

```
   class ListCreateRequisite(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
       serializer_class = RequisiteSerializer
       queryset = Requisite.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `create` method is not calling because `created_by` model field validation of require-field is catch before it when `serailizer.is_valid()` called. You need to assign that value, before calling serializer or in run time or even you can change created_by requirements in model defination. That will allow you to by pass this catch.

Comment: how do i do this?;

Comment: do your `RequisiteSerializer` is also responsible for adding user model ?

Comment: nop.. Its just to know which user has created it...it should automatically fill as loggged in user

Comment: ok, there are many possible way to do that, may be easiest one is to change ` created_by = ElsUserSerializer()` to ` created_by = ElsUserSerializer(read_only=True)`, if this is not working kindly please give me a feed back.